# Max number of values that can be provided in Spark Filter condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql

If I have a spark filter condition as below:

```
df2 = df1.filter("Status = 2 OR Status = 3")
```

What is the max number of values that I can provide for `Status` in the filter condition?

Comment: I don't think there is a limitation here, but having a massive amount of OR conditions doesn't make much sense to me, not to mention that you can easily get OOM. Using `~isin(2, 3, ...)` (i.e. not in) might be a better idea.

Comment: @pltc Do you know if there is a limit on the number of values that can be used with either ~in() or ~isin()?

Comment: There is no limit as far as I know